# Paginate entries based on related status

Tags: pagination, mysql, query, queries

So, let's assume I have two channels. `events` and `movies`, being `events` the screening time of each movie. In the admin, in the event entry, you can select one movie.

The movie could be disabled. The agenda page, a chronological list of the `events` shows up. I want to paginate the events, but only the ones with an enabled `movie`.

I've tried some stuff (see below), but ended up with the same result: A list of events, and some of them with an empty movie attribute.

So I want to exclude the events with no show from the result to paginate.

I've tried:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries({
    section: 'events',
    with: [
        ['show', { status: 'live' }],
    ],
    limit: 10,
}) %}
```

and:

```
{% set entries = craft.entries.section('events').with('show') %}
```

And to paginate:

```
    {% for entry in pageEntries %}
        <article>
            {{ entry.show[0].title }}
        </article>
    {% endfor %}

    {% if pageInfo.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.prevUrl }}">Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
    {% if pageInfo.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ pageInfo.nextUrl }}">Next Page</a>{% endif %}
```